# Running xgettext or creating .pot files without shell access?

Tags: php, shell, gettext, shared

I've been reading and reading about using gettext to internationalise a PHP website and it is interesting to me.

I am really stuck with actually creating the initial .pot file.

From reading around it appears I need to use the xgettext command within a shell to create my .pot file for my initial translations to then edit using Poedit.

My problem is I am on a shared server with no access to the Shell, exec() command or anything like this.

Is there any way to create this .pot file without using the shell or to create this file manually?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you don't have to do it on the server. Download the files to your local system and run it there.

Comment: Thanks for this response and sorry for the late reply, this worked a treat!